# How to reset IIS (or otherwise clear cache) when restarting a web application?

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2008, iis, caching

I'm working on an ASP.NET app that keeps a lot of data cached. This data remains cached when I restart the app, so I have to reset IIS if I want to rerun the code that gets the data, otherwise it's just taken from the cache. Is there a way that I can automate this?

Comment: Adrianos' question is quite important. Where is this data stored ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Running `iisreset` from an elevated (on Vista/Win7/Win2008) command prompt will restart IIS and all hosted applications. This is very quick if you keep the command prompt open: up arrow and enter to repeat last command.

Answer (score 1):

Where are you storing the data? In the application object?

If so, try calling Application.Clear() in the Application_Start method in global asax

Comment: I think that if the app restarts, the application object will be empty anyway.

Comment: The data is stored in `System.Web.Caching.Cache`

Comment: Cheers Timores, that's probably true.  Dave, on http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.caching.cache.aspx I noticed this link http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/edfcywt6(v=VS.100).aspx which might be helpful to you